# Why my one-to-zero-one relationship always produce an inner join with entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

My classed are declared as follow:

```
[Table("Profil")]
public class Profil
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column("CodeUtilisateur")]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string UtilisateurId { get; set; }

    public string Nom { get; set; }

    public string Prenom { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UtilisateurId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

[Table("vwADUser")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Column("Mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my linq query.

```
var query = from profil in icDbContext.Profils
            select new
            {
                profil.Nom,
                profil.Prenom,
                profil.UtilisateurId,
                UserEmail = profil.User != null ? profil.User.Email : ""
            };

var result = query.ToList();
```

The query that is sent to the database produce an inner join with the view [dbo].[vwADUser].

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Nom] AS [Nom], 
    [Extent1].[Prenom] AS [Prenom], 
    [Extent1].[CodeUtilisateur] AS [CodeUtilisateur], 
    [Extent2].[Mail] AS [Mail]
    FROM  [ic].[Profil] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwADUser] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CodeUtilisateur] = [Extent2].[UserName]
```

I have also tried this query with same result.

```
var query = from profil in icDbContext.Profils
            join user in icDbContext.Users on profil.UtilisateurId equals user.UserName into gusers
            from guser in gusers.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
            {
                profil.Nom,
                profil.Prenom,
                profil.UtilisateurId,
                UserEmail = guser != null ? guser.Email : ""
            };

var result = query.ToList();
```

I tried to manually configure the relationship with a few variants of this command without success.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profil>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.User)
    .WithOptionalDependent();
```

Any idea on how to configure my relationship to produce a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN?

Comment: It looks as if your classes are missing some fields.

Comment: What data type is your Foreign Key SQL column? (And does it allow nulls)

Comment: The data type is a string and it's the UtilisateurId property. This column is the key of the table but also a foreign key to the other table.

Comment: And this left outer join example from the official docs does not work for you?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: I tried it but got the same inner join problem. I have updated the description to add this example.

Comment: ForeignKey attribute on wrong property.  Also the fluent model creation is wrong and should be: `modelBuilder.Entity<Profil>().HasOptional(x => x.User).WithRequired(z=>z.Profil);`  and you also need to add the Profil navigation property to the User class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[Table("Profil")]
public class Profil
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column("CodeUtilisateur")]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string UtilisateurId { get; set; }

    public string Nom { get; set; }

    public string Prenom { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

[Table("vwADUser")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Profil")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Column("Mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Profil Profil {get;set;}
}
```

This is how you would do it Fluently:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profil>()
  .HasOptional(x => x.User) // User is optional for Profil
  .WithRequired(z=>z.Profil); // but Profil is required for User
```

Comment: It worked. I had to inverse the foreign key declaration. But tell me, is it possible to have optional relation on both side or I must a least declare one side as required?

Comment: I'm not sure as I've never needed to implement a 0..1:0..1 relationship.  Many to Many, yes.